# CORS not working with Spring Boot when MaxUploadSizeExceededException thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm implementing a REST service with Spring Boot to upload a file making a Multipart POST request.
I set a maximum file size in the application.yml as below:

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-file-size: 1MB
      max-request-size: 1MB
```

My service also implements a CORS policy to allow requests from a client app hosted by a development React server:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${security.cors-origin:}")
    private String allowedOrigin;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, JwtDecoder decoder, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {

        return http
                .csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authCustomizer -> authCustomizer.requestMatchers(new MvcRequestMatcher(introspector, "/actuator/**")).permitAll())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authCustomizer -> authCustomizer.requestMatchers(new MvcRequestMatcher(introspector, "/integration/**")).permitAll())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authCustomizer -> authCustomizer.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.decoder(decoder)))
                .sessionManagement(sessionCustomizer -> sessionCustomizer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Add a specified host to the allowed origin for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing
     *
     * This is needed in development as the origin of the front-end (localhost:3000)
     * is different to the origin of the back-end (localhost:8080)
     *
     * @param registry the CorsRegistry to use to add the allowed origin
     */
    @Override
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "security", name="cors-origin")
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigin)
                .allowCredentials(true)
        ;
    }

}
```

I also have a ControllerAdvice to handle exceptions thrown by controllers and Spring:

```
    @RestControllerAdvice
    @Slf4j
    public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    
        @ExceptionHandler({ MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class })
        @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
        public FileUploadErrorMessage handleMaxUploadSizeExceededException(MaxUploadSizeExceededException ex, WebRequest request) {
            FileUploadErrorMessage errorMessage = new FileUploadErrorMessage("inputValidation", "invalid file");
            ValidationResult validationResult = new ValidationResult("invalid.logo.size");
            errorMessage.setErrors(new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(validationResult)));
    
            return  errorMessage;
        }                                    
}
```

The problem is that with the MaxUploadSizeExceededException, Spring Web doesn't add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the error response. It works fine for other (controllers thrown) exceptions.
I thought it was because the request doesn't go through any controllers as it's blocked by the framework (which throws the exception), but the weird thing is that if I don't handle MaxUploadSizeExceededException in the above ControllerAdvice, Spring returns a 500 Internal error with a response body and the CORS header as well!

Can anyone explain this behaviour and knows how to fix it?